# why namespace does not work in live server

Tags: php, class

code running in localhost but shows an error in the live server

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'controller\product' not found in /home3/ruknalna/example.com/index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home3/ruknalna/example.com/index.php on line 5

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'app/helper/setUserType.php';
include 'app/helper/autoloader.php';
$product = new controller\product();
?>
```

app/controller/product.php

```
<?php

namespace Controller;

class Product extends \model\product
{
     public function addProduct($postData, $filesData)
     {
          $this->setProduct($postData, $filesData);
          $this->create($postData['table'], $postData['productId']);
     }

     public function readProduct($table, $productId = null)
     {
          if ($productId) {
               return $this->read($table, $productId);
          }
          if (!$productId) {
               return $this->readAll($table);
          }
     }

     public function updateProduct($postData, $filesData)
     {
          $this->setProduct($postData, $filesData);
          $this->update($postData['table'], $postData['productId']);
     }

     public function deleteProduct($table, $productId, $productSize)
     {
          $this->delete($table, $productId, $productSize);
     }

     public function updateProductStock($checkoutItems)
     {
          $this->updateProductQty($checkoutItems);
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you run `composer update` on the live server? https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: it might be that the namespace is case sensetive for selectors so you need to do `$product = new Controller/Product` i dont know if there is a need for `()` because than it might look for functions don't take my word for it i am just a beginner